# How find a solution to this PDE $\frac{xf'_{x}}{f'_{y}}+\frac{yf'_{y}}{f'_{x}}+x+y=C$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> let $C$ is give the constant ,if the function $f(x,y)$ such
>   $$\dfrac{xf'_{x}}{f'_{y}}+\dfrac{yf'_{y}}{f'_{x}}+x+y=C$$

Find the all $f(x,y)$

**I found this problem one solution:** $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}-C$$ is such it,because 
$$f'_{x}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},f'_{y}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$
so
$$(xf'_{x}+yf'_{y})\left(\dfrac{1}{f'_{x}}+\dfrac{1}{f'_{y}}\right)=C$$

My question: this PDE Have other solution?if this solution  is uniqueness,then How prove it?

**this problem background is from this**

show that: the length of the portion of any tangent line to the astroid 
$$f(x,y)=0$$
cut off by the coordinate axes is constant $C$,find $f(x,y)$

**my idea:**
the tangent line is 
$$f'_{x}(X-x)+f'_{y}(Y-y)=0$$
so let $$x=0,\Longrightarrow Y=\dfrac{xf'_{x}}{f'_{y}}+y$$
let $$y=0\Longrightarrow X=\dfrac{yf'_{y}}{f'_{x}}+x$$
so
$$X+Y=C\Longrightarrow \dfrac{xf'_{x}}{f'_{y}}+\dfrac{yf'_{y}}{f'_{x}}+x+y=C$$

then I can't solve this equation.  Thank you for you help.

Comment: Could you clarify what PDE you are trying to solve? The title one doesn't match one in the body, and the function you found solves neither.

Comment: Hello,maybe $f'_{x}=1?$

Comment: just to make sure: $f'_{x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$? Because i'm used to writing $f_{x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis,I think so,in china somebook always write $f'_{x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,if we write $$y=f(x)$$
then  tangent line
$$Y-f(x)=f'(x)[X-x]$$then
$$X=-\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}+x,Y=f(x)-xf'(x)$$
so
$$f(x)-xf'(x)+x-\dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=C$$
Both sides of the x derivation
$$f'(x)-f'(x)-x[f'(x)]^2+1-\dfrac{[f'(x)]^2-f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow xf''(x)=\dfrac{f(x)f''(x)}{[f'(x)]^2}$$
case one $f''(x)=0$
then we have $$f(x)=kx+b$$
case 2: if
$f''(x)\neq 0$,then we have
$$[f'(x)]=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\Longrightarrow \sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{x}=C$$
so
$$\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}=C$$